# Redirect to root page on 403 response

Tags: reactjs, iis

I have a React App hosted on IIS. If I access an existing directory, such as `<app_url>/static/`, it returns a 403 response since there's no permission on that directory. I'd like to redirect the user to my root page (~/).

I have tried this:

```
<httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

This kinda works, it does return the root page, however, it tries to download the React bundles from `/static/` instead of '/' only.

What can I do here?

Comment: You can try using [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) to redirect `<app_url>/static/` to the `root page`, If there are any questions, please post your needs in detail, i will make demo for you.

Comment: @samwu thanks for your reply! It works, but in my browser it still shows up /static/, is there a way to overwrite that as well?

Comment: @samwu nvm! I changed the rule from Rewrite to Redirect and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I used this rule and it worked:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect Static" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="static" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

(Thanks to @samwu)